# Is there a simple way to compare these definite integrals:

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

I want to prove that:

$$
\int_0^{Dy} \int_0^{Dx} \frac{dxdy}{r^3}
 >> \int_0^{Dy} \int_0^{Dx}\frac{\cos(wx)}{r^3}dxdy,
$$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+l^2}$

I know that:

$$
\int_0^{Dy} \int_0^{Dx} \frac{dxdy}{r^3} \geq \int_0^{Dy} \int_0^{Dx} \frac{\cos(wx)}{r^3}dxdy
$$

Because $\frac{1}{r^3} \geq \frac{\cos(wx)}{r^3}$

But I wonder if is possible to measure how much bigger the first integral is.

Comment: what do $Dx,Dy$ mean in this context?

Comment: I am just integrating luminous flux over an area so $Dx, Dy$ is simply its size. Sorry if the notation is not very clear.

Comment: so you mean to integrate over some $(0, D_x) \times (0, D_y)$ rectangle for some small positive $D_x,D_y$?

Comment: Yes . Although the area may not be small. But the period of the cosine $T=\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega}$  is much smaller than $Dx$ and $ Dy$.